# Reload spring when a static will will be changed

Tags: angular, spring

I have a project with Gradle + Spring Boot + Angular 9. The frontend sources are located under path: myProject > src > main > webapp. To compile Angular I use ng build and the output will be generated in resources > public so that I can use ./gradlew bootRun to serve it.

The matter is I have always run the two commands to reload the changes:

1. `ng build`
2. `./gradlew bootRun`

Is there any way to automate this with gradle and get a behaviour similar to `ng serve` where the server is rebooted every time you change a source?

I have written a custom gradle task but I am not sure how link it with spring-devtools for reboot the server automatically when a file from `webapp/` changes.

```kotlin
tasks.register("bootRunAll") {
    project.exec {
        commandLine("cmd", "/c/myProject", "ng", "build")
    }
    dependsOn(tasks["bootRun"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your development, you can use the `Spring devTool`. With Gradle, add this to your project:

```
dependencies {
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
...
}
```

Then, you might want to configure your IDE, because some of them doesn't allow to refresh your `.class` files. For instance, with IntelliJ, you have to:

1. Access the registry and set `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running` to `true`
2. Enable the `Build project Automatically` in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compile`

But if you use a different IDE, I don't know all the steps.

Comment: But devtools just reboot the server using `bootRun` not `bootRunAll` so although for sources in `src/main/kotlin` it works, the frontend is not rebuilded. I still missing how to link this with `ng build` command which is needed to compile the frontend.

Comment: I'm trying to look for an answer. I'll come back to you if I do

Comment: Can't you use a development server for Angular ? In order to enjoy the `ng serve` command ? I think that it is the best option

Comment: Just partially. Acutally the project is a microservice behind a load balancer and it uses an IAM for authentication. So I can use `ng serve` for pure UI development but I can not use it for integration with the backend because routing, CORS issues, etc.